# D3: Surround mouse point with "Crosshair"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to surround the mouse point with a circle, much like a crosshair, and have this circle track the mouses movement. So far the best strategy I have is using D3 enter-update-exit:

1. Append circle on mouse point underpinned by data.
2. on mouse move add another circle to data array with data = new mouse point.
3. if data array exceeds 1, shift() the first value out.
4. update visualisation.

jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/kur2bbv9/1/ - though I think it's largely irrelevent as this strategy is fundamentally flawed. The circle appears as though it's lagging behind the cursor and flickers. A lot. Which I don't want.

Key part of code here:

```
function onMove() {

    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    var point = {x: m[0], y: m[1]};

    area.push(point)

    document.getElementById("svg").onmousedown = function() {
        mouseDown++;
        addNode(m);
    };
    document.getElementById("svg").onmouseup = function() {
        mouseDown--;
    };
    if (mouseDown > 0) {
        addNode(m);
    }

    //if theres two circles, remove the first leaving just the second.
    if (area.length > 1) {
        area.shift();
    }   
    var crosshair = svg.selectAll(".area")
        .data([area])

    crosshair
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("cx", m[0])
        .attr("cy", m[1])
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "grey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
        .attr("r", 30)  

    crosshair.enter()
        .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("cx", m[0])
            .attr("cy", m[1])
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "grey")
            .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
            .attr("r", 30)  

    crosshair.exit().remove()
};
```

Is there another way of accomplishing this? Happy to accept non D3 strategies.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your JSfiddle to display anything, so I'm not sure if I'm totally missing the point, but could you just use [a custom CSS cursor](http://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor) on top of your SVG element? It seems that [`.cur` cursor files have the most wide-spread support](https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/). That would be a native alternative for custom hacks (thus giving better performance), and it would also degradate gracefully on un-supported browsers.

Comment: Fiddle updated. I should mention that ultimately I will need to reference the radius of this "crosshair". Not sure I can do that with a custom CSS cursor? but will take a look, thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always attach a mouseMove event listener to the SVG element, and get its position relative to the element. Then you can use that position info in further D3 calculations. But I have to admit that from what I've seen, D3's performance is quite good, so I would imagine that somekind of "D3 native" solution should be possible as well. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience for giving it to you :)

Comment: Think I add something of a mental breakdown during that code. Occurs to me that I can continuously change the x and y coordinates of a single point on mouse move rather than adding/removing points from a data array. Will try with a single point when I get home and see if performance is improved.